# My Rewrite Rules are not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2

I'm facing a problem that I'm not able to correct.

I have a customer's web server with different elements :

in the root we have a WordPress installation.
then we have a folder named "logicieload" that contains a Yii2 Advanced App.

In this folder I have a .htaccess file with the following rules.

```
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /logicieload/

RewriteRule ^xyzoad(/.*)?$ backend/web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1
```

The frontend is working normally, but I'm not able to get to the backend by calling the following URL.

http://www.domain.com/logicieload/xyzoad/

Have you any clue what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[L]` at the end of backend rule so when matched the rest will not be processed.

Comment: Thank, you help me, but there was another problem in my Yii2 backend config. I had to add the right "baseUrl" for the "urlManager"